# RunOnce /Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer

I just logged in (Windows 7 x64) and saw RunOnce run with this command line:

```
C:\Windows\system32\runonce.exe /Explorer
```

... huh? What's going on?

---

#### Edit:

I know what RunOnce does, but I'm confused as to what `/Explorer` does; sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: This is a really interesting question. I tried runonce /? and it doesn't offer any documentation. Does it run this every time you log in?

Comment: @jcrawfordor: Nope, hadn't seen it before; I just saw it run today.

Comment: Did your computer install updates on the previous shutdown? I wonder if this is related to the installation/configuration of updates.

Comment: @jcrawfordor: Not that I know of... Installed Updates is telling me my last update was on the 13th. No new programs installed either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is Windows running things listed in your [RunOnce key(s) in the registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137367).

One of them probably just took longer than expected, so you got to see the actual RunOnce.exe window.

***EDIT**: A little more info:*

From [here](https://msmvps.com/blogs/dmartin/archive/2008/08/04/problemas-con-la-inicializaci-243-n-de-explorer-exe.aspx) (Bing-translated to English):

> Perhaps the most important moment of this phase is the automatic execution of programs present in the key of registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce. These programmes are implemented, as its name suggests, only once: at the time that a user with administrative privileges, log on to the machine. There is a programme responsible for carrying out this process: C:\Windows\system32\Runonce.exe. Called the "Runonce.exe /Explorer" command, which, if the user is Administrator of the computer, is responsible for executing the contents of the key RunOnce (which usually are downstream of the installation of a program).

From what I can tell (there's not much info on it), the "/Explorer" switch is what causes RunOnce.exe to be run against each entry in the keys.

Comment: Yeah I know, but the thing is, why `/Explorer`? What does that flag do?

Comment: @Mehrdad - There's a bit more info on it for you. but there's really not a lot of info out there about it -- especially the switches; my guess as to why the lack of information is because we, as users, really don't have a reason to run/use the switches (but Windows itself does).

Comment: Interesting, so it seems like it's not as interesting as I thought, haha. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

In Windows Vista and later, you *must* use the command `RunOnce.exe /explorer` to process commands and launch applications which are entered in the registry under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

The **/Explorer** switch is probably intended to prevent you processing these entries at the wrong time - i.e. when a user is already logged on - but this can easily be circumvented by using the switch.

In Windows XP and earlier, **RunOnce.exe** would process the contents of  keys in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

when launched *without* command line switches (which were ignored by the program anyway - unless somebody knows of a valid switch for those versions of **RunOnce.exe**).